# Swift functions inside a var

Tags: swift

I am learning Swift, and want to know how to add functions to a var,

here the JS example...

```
function suma (a, b){
    return a + b
}

console.log("sua suma::", suma(2,3))

function multiplica (a, b){
    return a * b
}

console.log("sua multiplik::", multiplica(2,3))

const operations = {
    suma,
    multiplica
}

console.log ("sum of first class::", operations.suma(2,3))
console.log ("mult of first class::", operations.multiplica(2,3))
```

so how do I achieve the same on Swift?

Here what I have tried:

```
import Foundation


func suma(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func multiplica(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int {
    return a * b
}

print("sua suma", suma(a: 2, b: 3))
print("sua multiplica", multiplica(a: 2, b: 3))

var operations = {
    suma
    multiplica
}


print("sua operatio", operations.suma(a: 2, b: 3)
```

So how to edit the Swift code to call the function inside operations?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a tuple for this:

```
let operations = (
    suma: suma
    multiplica: multiplica
)

print("sua operatio", operations.suma(2, 3)
```

Note that the names are duplicated. The one before the `:` is just a label so that you can refer to it with a name, and the one after the `:` actually refers to the function.

I would advise against writing Swift code in a JS style. You should not group functions together like this. Write a class/struct instead, and declare the functions in there. Use `static` where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As Sweeper mentioned in his answer the Swift equivalent of the JS code would probably be a class with static functions.

```
class Operations {
    static func suma(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int {
        return a + b
    }

    static func multiplica(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int {
        return a * b
    }
}
```

You would call the functions like this

```
print("sua operatio \(Operations.suma(a: 2, b: 3))")
```